# Error loading file pipe-separated text using odbc

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, odbc

I am making an import of data from a text delimited pipe (|) file into a Web page Asp net ... the code is as follows:

```
Dim rutaFuente As String = "c:\Logs\"
Dim archivosFuente As String = "DatosPersona.csv"
Using con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & rutaFuente & ";" _
                             & "Extended Properties=""TEXT;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited(|)""")

Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", archivosFuente), con)
    con.Open()

    Using adp As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim tbl As New DataTable("TablaArchivosSeparados")
        adp.Fill(tbl)
      GridView1.DataSource = tbl.TableName("TablaArchivosSeparados")
            GridView1.DataBind()

        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

but I get error on line adp.Fill(tbl) saying:

"It is already opened exclusively by another user or you need permission to view its data, and check that the file does not have read-only permission or any protection, or the directory is restricted".

these same lines of code have them on a console and work perfectly when I write (Console.writeline(item)) row of the data table For Each row As DataRow In tbl.Rows

```
   For Each row As DataRow In tbl.Rows
         For Each item In row.ItemArray
              Console.WriteLine(item)
         Next
   Next
```

why I get this error??

Comment: I don't wanna use third party libraries as http://www.filehelpers.net/ or http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

Comment: You didn't specify, so I'm going with the obvious that the account which your web app runs under does not have access to the file or the folder it's in.  Or another web process (presumably by a different user) is loading the page while you're accessing it - resulting in the 'already opened exclusively by another user' part.

Comment: the file and folder have All  the permission, does not have restrictions!